# Style 1 <td> in a table with 2 <td>s

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, echo

I have a table that gets it´s content from a database, and I want to make the text in the column to the right align-right. I know how to do it when its HTML and the content is in the code, but I can't get it to work when the content is outputted from a database.

Down here you can see my code for the table: (in the collumn "ingredienser", I want to set the text-align to right.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("****","****","****");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("paj", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meny");


echo "<div id='menyer'>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
    echo "<div class='mall" . $row['mall'] . "'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['namn'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ingredienser'] . "'</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add some CSS above your php code

```
<style>
table td {
   text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

The above will right align text inside table cells

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td><div align='right'>" . $row['ingredienser'] . "'</div></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is the extent of your table, then you can definitely just use the following css:

```
.mall{
    text-align:right;
}
```

I would suggest putting it in your external css file, but if you don't have one, then put it in a style tag inside of your body or table tag, depending on what kind of scope you want it to have like this:

```
<style>
.mall{
    text-align:right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `align="right"` to your `tr`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { 
    echo "<div class='mall" . $row['mall'] . "'>";
    echo "<tr align='right'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['namn'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ingredienser'] . "'</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add styling to that one particular cell, it will apply to the entire column as it loops. As such,

`echo "<td style=\"text-align:right;\">" . $row['ingredienser'] . "'</td>";`

If you align the Table TD to `text-align:right`, EVERY single cell will be effected.